# Kernel Function in Gaussian Processes

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian, kernel-density

Given a kernel in Gaussian Process, is it possible to know the shape of functions being drawn from the prior distribution without sampling at first?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. How many observations does a GP have? If you say that a function is sampled from the prior, how can a GP effect it? Also, what do you mean by shape?

Comment: You got it right! The sampled functions are drawn from prior and they do not depend on GP. I am assuming prior is multi-variate Gaussian with zero mean and a covariance matrix (defined by kernel). Now you are given the kernel say squared exponential or brownian motion etc. Is it possible to tell how smooth or varying the sampled functions will be from this prior? f ~ N (0, \sigma), here \sigma is covariance matrix and calculated by the definition of kernel.

Comment: Got you. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to know the shape of prior functions is to draw them. Here's 1-dimensional example:

[image: prior samples]

These are the samples from the GP prior (mean is 0 and covariance matrix induced by the squared exponential kernel). As you case see they are smooth and generally it gives a feeling how "wiggly" they are. Also note that in case of multi-dimensions each one of them will look somewhat like this.

Here's a full code I used, feel free to write your own kernel or tweak the parameters to see how it affects the samples:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

def kernel(a, b, gamma=0.1):
    """ GP squared exponential kernel """
    sq_dist = np.sum(a**2, 1).reshape(-1, 1) + np.sum(b**2, 1) - 2*np.dot(a, b.T)
    return np.exp(-0.5 * (1 / gamma) * sq_dist)

n = 300       # number of points.
m = 10        # number of functions to draw.
s = 1e-6      # noise variance.

X = np.linspace(-5, 5, n).reshape(-1, 1)
K = kernel(X, X)
L = np.linalg.cholesky(K + s * np.eye(n))
f_prior = np.dot(L, np.random.normal(size=(n, m)))

pl.figure(1)
pl.clf()
pl.plot(X, f_prior)
pl.title('%d samples from the GP prior' % m)
pl.axis([-5, 5, -3, 3])
pl.show()
```